# How would you go about creating a class diagram for a JPA/JSF application

Tags: class-diagram

I was creating a class diagram for an application I was working on today and I didnt include the JPA entities since I had all the information I thought was important in my DAOs, for example, I just care about how to register a user regardless of what information does a User object contain, so I only included the UserDao in my class diagram and added an operation called register which has a parameter of type User without having a User class in my diagram.

My question is if its necessary to include every single class I have in my diagram or can I omit the classes that I will be forced to add because I am using a certain framework such as JSF or JPA?

Answer (score 1):

I certainly wouldn't include the classes generated from HTML page templates in a class diagram.  But it's your diagram.  Include whatever you want.  Who is your audience?

Comment: The audience will be programmers who are familiar with the technologies I mentioned

Comment: My guess is that they won't want to see the views.  They are only Java classes by accident.  The models are the interesting part.  I wouldn't include the controllers either.